# finding the URL of the document that loaded the current document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

finding the URL without server activity and 
without the func() document.referrer.??
it should be secured.

Answer (score 0):

Over secure connections no referrer header is sent.

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
>   HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
>   protocol.

*Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html (about a third of the way down the page)*